# C# Randomly pick value from table with specify pattern

Tags: c#, random

I would like to have 4 list of data which are 12 randomly picked data on each row in those table  with a designated pattern of "*".

I did try use Random() function but it was not working as the desire output.

Below are my sample code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvA1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    int row = 0; int col = 0;

                    //Get First Row
                    for (int x = 0; x < 12;x++)
                    {
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int randomNumber = r.Next(1, 35); //for ints
                        row = randomNumber;
                        col = randomNumber;
                        rbLog.Text += row.ToString() + ";" + col.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

Below are the picture of the table, and the red line are the coordinate that i wanted to be randomly selected on each of the line.
[image]

Total will be 4 line of random picked with 12 data each line. Any other method or linQ can done that?

Thanks

Comment: How can it be random if its pre-determined to fall in a certain pattern ?

Comment: It's a 2d grid ? you have issue getting the column slice, row slice?  having their index will just be division by 2 on the total of row and column. For diagonals 2 nested `for` will be able to that. A simple +1 / -1.

Comment: @DragandDrop mean?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee for each of the line, i would like to randomly picked 12 data

Comment: You need 12 set of random indices from [`principal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal) and [`secondary diagonal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal#Antidiagonal) right ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started -

```
List<(int, int)> principalDiagonalIndices = new List<(int, int)>();
List<(int, int)> secondaryDiagonalIndices = new List<(int, int)>();

int rowCount = dgvA1.Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
    {
        if (i == j)
        {
            principalDiagonal.Add((i, j));
        }
        else if ((i + j) == (rowCount - 1))
        {
            secondaryDiagonalIndices.Add((i, j));
        }
    }
}

Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    var principalIdx = principalDiagonalIndices[r.Next(0, principalDiagonalIndices.Count)];
    Console.WriteLine("Random principal diagonal index - {0}", dgvA1[principalIdx.Item1, principalIdx.Item2]);
    
    var secondaryIdx = secondaryDiagonalIndices[r.Next(0, secondaryDiagonalIndices.Count)];
    Console.WriteLine("Random secondary diagonal index - {0}", dgvA1[secondaryIdx.Item1, secondaryIdx.Item2]);
}
```

Collect the principal and secondary diagonal in the list and iterate 12 times to get a pseudo-random index.

For principal diagonal, if you observe the row and column are equal `(i == j)`.

And for secondary diagonal it should be `row` and `col` index summed up should equal to one minus the row-count.